How to manually commit message after kafka processing
I create the kafka config with auto commit disabled:
    // Create Kafka consumer with auto-commit disabled
    kafkaConfig := &kafka.ConfigMap{}
    err := kafkaConfig.SetKey("enable.auto.commit", "false")

My consumer reads the message to a worker:
func (c *consumer) start() {
    c.running = true
    for c.running {
        // read the message from Kafka (does NOT commit the offset)
        msg, err := c.k.ReadMessage(-1)
        if err == nil {
            // send the message to the channel for processing by workers
            c.msgChan <- msg

I want my worker to commit the message after successful processing:
func worker(id int, c *consumer) {
    for c.running {
        select {
        case msg, ok := <-c.msgChan:
            if !ok { // Channel closed
                return
            }

            timestamp := strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix()*1000, 10)
            m, err := newMessage(msg.Value, timestamp)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Worker %d: Error creating new message: %v\n", id, err)
                break
            }

            payload, err := m.stringifyMessage()
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Worker %d: Error decoding message to JSON string: %v\n", id, err)
                break
            }

            key := uuid.New()
            status := c.r.Set(context.Background(), key.String(), string(payload), time.Hour*6)
            if status.Err() != nil {
                log.Printf("Worker %d: Failed to persist message %s. %v\n", id, key.String(), status.Err())
                break
            }

            connID := m.getConnectionID()
            log.Printf("Worker %d:\t%s\tconnection:\t%s", id, key.String(), connID)

            // Commit the offset after successful processing
            _, commitErr := c.k.CommitMessage(msg)
            if commitErr != nil {
                log.Printf("Worker %d: Failed to commit message: %v (%v)\n", id, commitErr, msg)
            }

        case _ = <-c.sigChan:
            c.running = false
            return // Exit the worker gracefully
        }
    }
}

but building the image gives

#0 8.386 ./worker.go:44:24: c.k.CommitMessage undefined (type Kafka has no field or method CommitMessage)

EDIT: changing it to _, commitErr := c.CommitMessage(msg) still gives the same error:

#0 9.260 ./worker.go:44:22: c.CommitMessage undefined (type *consumer has no field or method CommitMessage)

Using "github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka"

This query to a popular internet search service yields this result which means the CommitMessage is a method of Consumer.

A little bit more searching yields this overview about consumers and committing messages.

Please clarify which go client you're using

@OneCricketeer using "github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka"

CommitMessage should work, if not, report an issue and maybe try a different version https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues

Which type is c and c.k? If it's your own types that essentially wraps the Kafka library types, then you'll need to add a new CommitMessage method that internally calls the library.
